SATA options & conflicts for dual booting windows and Linux
I am currently on a laptop running windows 11 and was looking to dual boot into arch preferably. However when I tried installing arch no recognised drives could be found.
I then found by searching that this was just to SATA. I had three options in my BIOS for it. Disabled, ACHI, and RAID.
The laptop was currently on RAID but if I changed the SATA to either disabled or ACHI windows either doesn’t have a boot option or blue screens when I try to.
I have system restore points on windows but I am confused from things online on what the best approach is. Do i set to disabled and fully reinstall windows / (can i use a restore point if i do?) or is there a way to allow windows to boot with SATA disabled.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Windows 11 only supports booting in UEFI mode from GPT disk.

You need to start Windows in Safe Mode, then change the disk controller from RAID to AHCI mode, then put Windows back into normal boot mode.
I described how to do this here:
https://www.theregister.com/2022/07/22/linux_nonapproved_laptop/

Exactly what I needed this was perfect thank you!
